# How to disable interactions of all Components at once in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, overlay, disabled-input

I have a Column (not full screen) containing a few components like TextFiled, Chip, etc.. and There's a Submit button and I need to disable all component interactions (Click, Type) once this button is clicked.

Is there any proper and simple way to fulfill this requirement without disabling each Component one by one?

Eg. Display transparent overlay

Comment: You can use ```Box``` Composable and Keep your ```Column``` first and then add another column or overlay compsable and just Maintain its state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a **sibling** Box composable and set click listener on it based on a flag you will be able to disable every interaction.

[image]

```
@Composable
fun TouchDisable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    disableTouch: Boolean,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    LaunchedEffect(disableTouch) {
        if (disableTouch) {
            focusManager.clearFocus()
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        content()
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize().then(
                if (disableTouch) {
                    Modifier.clickable(
                        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                        indication = null,
                        onClick = {}
                    )
                } else {
                    Modifier
                }
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Demo

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun TouchTest() {
    Column {

        var disableTouch by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Text") }

        Button(
            onClick = {
                disableTouch = disableTouch.not()
            }
        ) {
            Text("Disabled: $disableTouch")
        }

        TouchDisable(
            disableTouch = disableTouch,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(200.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Red)
        ) {
            Column {
                Button(
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    Text("Button1")
                }

                Button(
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    Text("Button2")
                }

                TextField(
                    text,
                    onValueChange = { text = it }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but if there are TextFiled(s) and focus on any before disabling touch, even after disabling touch, there will be displaying curser and still able to type. Also, need to backpress to hide the keyboard manually. I have made a small modification to disable the above using the below code. Is there another proper way to do this?3

`if (disableTouch) {
 val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
  focusManager.clearFocus()
}`

Comment: @AndroidDev thanks for pointing it out. Updated answer to remove focus as well.